# using always() with if statement in github action does not work

Tags: github-actions

I have the following GitHub action, and I have a manual input for "true" or "false". If the option is "false" the statement  `inputs.test == true` is false but because the "always()" it still go into the action

I need the "always" because I always want to perform the action here.

For example: always send a slack message, but only if the user did not choose "false".

How can I achieve that?

This is the action I have tried:

```
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ inputs.test == true }} && always()  
    needs: [smth]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: test
        id: test-status
        run: |
          echo do smth
```

Comment: According to what you explained, you don't really need the `always()` function at the `job` level here, because the job will always run by default. However, you could add an expression `if: ${{ inputs.test == 'true' }}` at the `step` level to perform or not a specific operation if the input is false, still doing the other job steps if that makes sense.